# php variables in javascript appended html; syntax

Tags: javascript, php, syntax

To explain what I am doing:
I have a row of form inputs, but let's just consider a radio input. It's name is "OpenClose1", corresponding to being on row 1. Within that input field I have a php snippet to find if a variable has been set ($OpenClose), in order to "checked" the input or not. This is to repopulate the form on error or what else, with data already entered obviously.

Now, in my program I can add rows dynamically and I accomplish this via javascript's .appendTo('myhtmljunk'). In the function that "appends" this html, I know the row number and it is assigned to a var. I need to be able to include my php snippet that checks the php variable $OpenClose1 (or whatever row number) So the problem I am having with syntax, or if it's even possible, is that I need to change the "1" of the php variable to my JS var 'RowNum'. Is an awkward mashup of languages and I could use some help. I have a basic code example below:

```
var RowNum = 2;

$('<div class="<?php if(isset($OpenClose1) && $OpenClose1){ echo "ClosedClass"; } ?>"><input type="radio">Stuff</div>').appendTo('someDiv');

//Clearly doesn't work, but what I am wanting to do
$('<div class="<?php if(isset($OpenClose'+RowNum+') && $OpenClose'+RowNum+'){ echo "ClosedClass"; } ?>"><input type="radio">Stuff</div>').appendTo('someDiv');

//This obviously does not work either, but another example
$('<div class="<?php if(isset($OpenClose?>'+RowNum+'<?php) && $OpenClose?>'+RowNum+'<?php){ echo "ClosedClass"; } ?>"><input type="radio">Stuff</div>').appendTo('someDiv');
```

How can I get the number "1" of a php variable to be the JS var **RowNum**

Thank you all!

Comment: One thing that can help you is to use [ternary conditions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to print

Comment: PHP works on the server side. JavaScript works on the client side. When you add things via JavaScript, they have nothing to do with the server. Also, you really need to separate your code out, I'd suggest using PHP to create hidden inputs, and then get the value of those inputs with JavaScript.

Comment: Ahhhh!!! I typed all this out and just realized my structure is off; I'm trying to do something I don't even need to do! Sorry!

Comment: You should delete your question if it's no longer applicable.